# streaming data from Wcf client to Java server

Tags: java, .net, wcf, web-services, streaming

Our situation: we have a java server side, here is the definition of the WebService:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "upload")
void upload(
 @WebParam(name = "User", partName = "User", header = true) String user,
 @WebParam(name = "Pwd",partName = "Pwd",header = true) String password,
 @WebParam(name = "Filename",partName = "Filename",header = true) String filename,
 @WebParam(name = "Data", partName = "Data",targetNamespace = "http://") @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
DataHandler data) throws InvalidRequestException, ServiceException;
```

Our client is written in c#. The autogenerated Wcf client side request parameter for the "upload" method is:

```
public partial class uploadRequest {
 [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://", Order=0)]
 [XmlArrayAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
 [XmlArrayItemAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
 public Property[] Properties;

 [MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://", Order=1)]
 [XmlElementAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="base64Binary")]
 public byte[] Data;

 public uploadRequest() {}

 public uploadRequest(Property[] Properties, byte[] Data) {
  this.Properties = Properties;
  this.Data = Data;
 }
}
```

This code is working well, but we need the Data as Stream instead of byte[] because we want to upload large files. I now, for the streaming we need the "Properties" defined for the Header and not for the body (and naturally some changings in the config file), but the problem is: this is autogenerated.

**My question:** how can we force the wcf client side to generate correct code for us? Or should we change the server side to achieve that?